# My ajax code don't send the data to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, database

I want to use ajax to add data in the database but nothing happens
i don't know whats wrong is it in the ajax!or in the php
This is part of my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
          $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#commentForm").submit(function(){

            var U_N = $('input[name="U_N"]').val();
            var I_name = $('input[name="I_name"]').val();
            var context = $("#inputmessage").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,  
                url : "aAddComm_Menu.php",
                data : {U_N:U_N,I_name:I_name,context:context},

            });

    });
    });//end of document ready function             
                </script>
```

this the html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputmessage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">comment</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea name = "context" class="form-control" id="inputmessage"  rows="3" placeholder="Enter your comment here . . "></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>  <!-- End of /.form-group -->


                        <input type="hidden" value = "$Item['Item_Name']" name="I_name"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value ="$U_N"  name="U_N"/>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button name="SendC" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ;>Send</button>
                            </div>




                        </div>  

                    </form>
```

and this is a part of the php page for adding to the database

```
extract($_POST)

if(isset($context))
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO menu_commnet VALUES('$I_name','$U_N',NULL,NOW(),'$context')");

}
```

Comment: 1. Open developers console. 2. Check your php-file for errors - for example after `extract($_POST)` should be `;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var U_N = $("input#U_N").val();
var I_name = $("#I_name").val();
var context = $("#context").val();
```

The jQuery selectors are wrong, you're not selecting anything. The `#` selector stands for `id` attribute, but you're trying to select by value of `name` attribute. You should either add/change `id` attributes of your input fields, or use

```
var U_N = $("input[name=U_N]").val();
var I_name = $("input[name=I_name]").val();
var context = $("[name=context]").val();
```

---

Tip: next time use [developer console inside your browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), you can easily test if selectors are correct. You can type in javascript code as you would inside .js file and test if it's working like you expect.

Also, don't do this in your PHP, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: i opened the console and changed some things but it's still doesn't work
what's about the prepared statements i have must use or it's ok without?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "opened the console and changed some things". You have to fix it in your javascript file, not "some things" in console, because what you do in console resets after you refresh the browser.  You were using wrong selectors with jQuery, that's why your ajax didn't send anything. I'm not sure what you're doing in your php so I can't help with that. And you don't necessarily need prepared statements, but it's recommend that you do use them, because otherwise your database queries are prone to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you included you Database conection on your Backend script?
extract($_POST)

```
'if(isset($context)) {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO menu_commnet VALUES('$I_name','$U_N',NULL,NOW(),'$context')");
 }'
```

i think here you should include you database info, 'include_once("database info.php"); , also make sure you ajax will return a result, and echo php errors, just to be sure its an ajax or php error,

Comment: you can append the result to some html div, with success:function if it's a php error and you have error control on you backend it will return the php error code, if it doesn't it wont return anything

Answer (score 0):

I have few comment regarding  your issue :

1. Replace `$("document").ready(function(){` with
   `$(document).ready(function(){`
2. Before extracting in PHP ,
       try `var_dump($_POST)`
3. Based on your HTML code use:

   var U_N = $('input[name="U_N"]').val();

   var I_name = $('input[name="I_name"]').val();

   var context = $("#inputmessage").val();

Answer (score 0):

Here is final working example. Just add "ev" argument to submit callback function , then use ev.preventDefault() in it.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#commentForm").submit(function(ev){

                ev.preventDefault();

                var U_N = $('input[name="U_N"]').val();
                var I_name = $('input[name="I_name"]').val();
                var context = $("#inputmessage").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    url : "aAddComm_Menu.php",
                    data : {U_N:U_N,I_name:I_name,context:context}

                });

            });
        });//end of document ready function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputmessage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">comment</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea name="context" class="form-control" id="inputmessage" rows="3"
                      placeholder="Enter your comment here . . "></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>



    <input type="text" value="" name="I_name"/>
    <input type="text" value="" name="U_N"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button name="SendC" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: still doesn't work ><
in the form i think this the right thing about hidden value <input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $I_name;?>" name="I_name"/>
        <input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $U_N; ?>" name="U_N"/>